Am I violating exchangeability in my attempt to measure average treatment effect
I am wondering if I am about to violate the exchangeability assumption in an observational study where I want to speak about the causal effect of a treatment (i.e. ATE - average treatment effect).
The exchangeability assumption states that (read $ \perp $ as independence):
$$Y^a \perp A | W \, , $$
for an outcome variable $Y$, treatment variable $A$ and remaining covariates $W$.
In my case $A$ is a treatment which may or may not affect $Y$ which is a health condition - may be average blood sugar level. The issue that concerns me is that the covariates in $W$ contain measures of other health conditions such as eGFR (measure of how well the kidney is working), BMI and so on, plus the standard covariates as age and sex etc.
Therefore, there if $A$ has an effect on $Y$ then this will probably have an effect on the covariates in $W$, which are known to be affected by the outcome of $Y$. I.e. if $A$ lowers $Y$ then this might support some of the covariates in $W$ in a positive manner.
One solution would of course be to make a study, and have baseline measures of $W$, but I do not have this. I have a cross-sectional study with measures given at approximately the same intervals of time. Is there a way for me to isolate the effect of $A$ on $Y$ when conditioning on $W$ and thereby make a causal statement? Or is there some other way to go about this?

Effects of the form $A \rightarrow Y \rightarrow W$ do not contradict the exchangeability assumption for the experiment, but effects of the form $A \rightarrow Y^a \rightarrow W$ (or even just $A \rightarrow Y^a$) do contradict it.$^\dagger$  The latter effect would mean that the treatment allocation affects the outcome that will occur under a particular treatment and through this it affects the covariates.
The exchangeability assumption essentially says that the treatment must not be statistically related to the outcomes that would occur under each possible treatment, and this must hold regardless of the covariates.  This assumption is usually met by randomising the treatment allocation (using a procedure that is not biased based on covariate information) and imposing blinding protocols that prevent an indirect effect of the form $A \rightarrow W \rightarrow Y$.  Effects of the form $A \rightarrow Y \rightarrow W$ are not a problem for the experiment and they do not contradict the required exchangeability assumption --- indeed, since they are causal effects from the treatment to the outcome they are exactly the thing that is of interest in the experiment.

$^\dagger$ To understand this issue it is important to note the distinction between $Y$ and $Y^a$.  The outcome $Y^a$ is the (actual or counterfactual) outcome that obtains under the treatment $A=a$.  The actual outcome that occurs in the experiment is the outcome $Y \equiv \sum_{a \in \mathscr{A}} Y^a \cdot \mathbb{I}(A=a)$.

Allright so there would essentially be some treatment allocation going on that would have an a priori association/relationship with the outcome under treatment/non-treatment $Y^a$ ? Or perhaps not this only case, but this would violate the exchangeability assumption?
Thank you very much by the way!

Whether or not there is an effect of $a$ in $Y^a$ is the causal question of interest.  If $Y=Y^a$ for all $a \in \mathscr{A}$ then that is telling you that the treatment has no effect on the outcome.  Contrarily, if $Y^a \neq Y^{a'}$ for some $a,a' \in \mathscr{A}$ then there is a causal effect from the treatment.
